# Remove specific parts of an audio sample

Tags: java, audio

I'm fairly new to java and I'm having a problem trying to remove specific parts of an audio sample. The audio is 64513 samples long. I'm trying to remove roughly samples 16000-32000. I'm not quite sure how exactly to remove the specific parts of what I believe is a collection?

```
import Media.*;                  // for Picture and Sound etc.

import java.awt.*;               // for Color objects and methods

import static java.lang.Math.*;  // for math constants and functions

import static java.awt.Color.*;  // for Color constants

public Censoring ( ) {

    Sound sound;
    Sound newCensor;

    player = new SoundPlayer();
    sound = new Sound();
    player.placeSound(sound);
    player.waitForUser();
    newCensor = censor(sound, 16000, 32000);
    player.close();
    sound.save(); 

}; 




private Sound censor ( Sound aSound, int from, int to) {
  Sound result;
  Sample s;
  int numSamples;      
  numSamples = aSound.getNumSamples();

  result = new Sound(s, aSound);
  for( int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++ ){

    if( i <= from && i >= to) { 
      s = aSound.getSample(i);
    }; 

  }; 
  return result;



};
```

This is the error I get from the "result = new Sound(s, aSound);"

```
Error: incompatible types: Media.Sample cannot be converted to int
```

I believe that I have chosen all the sample values (i), that I want to keep from the sound file, but how do I use the new samples to make a new Sound? Thanks.

Comment: What are `SoundPlayer` and `Sound`?

Comment: The class SoundPlayer presents a window on screen with a button to be pressed to play a sound. Once that has been created, a sound object (selected from a file in .wav format) can be placed into the player allowing it to be played.

Comment: Looks like your `Media.Sample` class does not have a `remove` method. Or maybe it does have one, but needs different parameters. Where does your `Media.Sample` class come from? It might help if you include your imports in the code.

Comment: Added them in at the top

Comment: Great! I've edited it a bit - indenting by 4 spaces puts it in code markdown. Unfortunately it doesn't give me the information I was hoping for - the origin of this `Media` package. The error seems to apply to this `Media.Sample` class. If we can find the documentation for that, we might be able to find the method call(s) that you need. So - where does this `Media` package come from? Or rather, do you have documentation for it?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly to do with the package files but I uploaded it quickly if you wanted to take a look. https://www.dropbox.com/s/nyxctb4g52eqv9w/Media.jar?dl=0

Comment: Ok, it looks like [this](https://www.cosc.brocku.ca/sites/all/files/documentation/Brock_packages/index.html?Media/package-summary.html) is the documentation - from Brock university, Canada?

Comment: Yes, that would be it. Didn't even know this was a thing, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The error message informs you that the `Media.Sample` class does not have a `remove(Sound)` method.
Looking at the [documentation](https://www.cosc.brocku.ca/sites/all/files/documentation/Brock_packages/Media/Sample.html), we find that this is correct - it only has methods to change the amplitude.

This seems to be a homework assignment. I'm not entirely sure what your professors are looking for. Myself, I would create a new `Sound` from the samples you want to keep.

Comment: Could I reverse it and look for the samples outside of the "from" and "to" parameters, then create a new sample size? Also I'm still confused on what I would be returning? Would I just be returning "aSound"?

Comment: You'd create a new  `Sound` instance, put everyting outside the `from` and `to` in it, and return that. Also, in the `main` method, you'll want to assign that to a variable: `Sound censoredSound=censor(sound,16000,32000);` . Since it's probably homework, you may want to discuss it with your fellow students. The professor may want you to use specific techniques.

Comment: I changed some of it around to get the samples for "i" that aren't in between "from" and "to" although I'm not sure how it would even grab the correct samples instead of just shortening the entire sound file? Sorry to keep asking questions.